# NSXMLParser not adding all objects in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

When I try to parse the XML file using NSXMLParser I could not parse all the elements ..
XML response looks like this:

```
<AList>
   <Details>
          <AId>1</AId>
          <Date>10/31/2012</Date>
          <Time>11:00 AM</Time>
       <User>
          <Employee>
              <Name>Rosy</Name>
              </Employee>
              <Company>
                  <Customer>
                     <CustName>Williams</CustName>
                     <CustPhone>1232322</CustPhone>
                 </Customer>
             </Company>
       </User>
  </Details>
<Details>
          <AId>2</AId>
          <Date>10/31/2012</Date>
          <Time>11:30 AM</Time>
       <User>
          <Employee>
              <Name>Mary</Name>
              </Employee>
              <Company>
                  <Customer>
                     <CustName>Christopher</CustName>
                     <CustPhone>123233323</CustPhone>
                 </Customer>
             </Company>
       </User>
  </Details>
</AList>
```

How can I get all the elemnts in all the XML tags?

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {


if([elementName isEqualToString:@"AList"])
{
    arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



}
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Details"]||[elementName isEqualToString:@"User"])
    {
        drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

srr=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];

} 


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{


    [srr appendString:string];
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"AId"])
    {

        [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"AId"];
        [srr release],srr=nil;
        return;
    }  

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Date"])
    {

        [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"Date"];
        [srr release],srr=nil;
       return;    
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Time"])
    {

        [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"Time"];
        [srr release],srr=nil;
     return;      
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"])
    {

        [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"Name"];
        [srr release],srr=nil;
        return;
    }
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CustName"])
    {
        [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"CustName"];
        [srr release],srr=nil;


       return;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CustPhone"])
    { 
        [arr addObject:drr]; 

    }    



    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"AList"])
    {

        [drr release];


    }

    [srr release],srr=nil;

}
```

I dont want CustPhone...I couldget only CustName from the code i have written.Where Im going wrong?

Comment: please post some code related to the issue...

Comment: I added code.Can u please have a look and let me know where im going wrong..

Comment: what is the issue ? Do you get any element ? Is the delegate methods working ?

Comment: I m getting only CustName in the array..My array in the result is  (
        {
        CustName = Williams;
    },
        {
        CustName = Christopher;
    },
        
)

Comment: I m getting only CustName in the array..My array in the result is  (
        {
        CustName = Williams;
    },
        {
        CustName = Christopher;
    },
        
) Im not getting all the elements...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the link http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser. Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

your < /Alist> TAG is different from < AList> - **'L'**. else NSXMLParser could easy parse all other tags data for you properly in `didFoundCharacters` delegate.

here is ur problem in string comparison in

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"AList"]) // in ur xml it is Alist
{

    [drr release];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please change this

```
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Details"]||[elementName isEqualToString:@"User"])
    {
        drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
```

to

```
   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Details"])
    {
        drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
```

You are adding the dictionary to array when the customer phone element is found.
You are allocating the dictionary twice. When the "**Details**" and "**User**" tags found.

Comment: When I wrote ur code Im getting only Name and CustName like this (
        {
        CompanyName = Williams;
        Name = Rosy;
    },
        {
        CompanyName = Christopher;
        Name = Mary;
    },
       
)
I m not getting the other AId,Date,Time...What elz should I change?

Comment: @arizah: put NSlog in the didEndElement and print the content of srr. Check the output

Comment: I couldnot get u .Can u please explain me briefly...I kept it like this:NSLog(@"%@",srr);I got srr as 0

Comment: Put `NSLog(@"%@",srr);' as the first line of `didEndElement:` method. Please check the console, is it displaying the date and AId in the console ?

Comment: I kept it and ckecked it by keeping a break point and Im getting it in console.Yes Im getting it in console.But in the final arr Im not getting

Comment: One more check, is it entering to the if block's of AId and Date ?

Comment: Yes it is entering to the if block's of AId and Date but not getting finally